# Read txt file from specified string to specified string

Tags: vb.net

Welcome ,
i have a text file with specified format like this :

```
"King": {
  "name": "Jack",
  "Age": "23",
  "ID": "001",
},

"Queen": {
  "name": "Lory",
  "Age": "19",
  "ID": "002",
  "Pass": "955",
},
```

how can i read the "King" from `{` To `},`
and check if the text contains `"Pass"` or no .

and how can i replace the `"Age"` of `King` because when i do that every `Age` word will be replaced.

any help would be appreciated
& sorry for my little speak .

Comment: Please Show some effort first, people will help to improve your code, not write it for you.

Comment: What language are you using? Answers will be slightly different (if any)... I agree with bash

Comment: Have you tried using a JSON parser to do all of this for you?

Comment: bash.d : my code is basic nothing special , Sayse : i'm using Visual Basic , Jon : i don't know how to use java :( .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thas seems to be a JSON file, so use a JSON parser, like [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) to load the file, parse and modify it.

For example

(we have to fight a little because your data doesn't have a "containing" { }, so we add them when we parse it and we remove them when we serialize)

```
' Adding a containing { }
Dim parsed As JObject = JObject.Parse("{ " & json & " }")
Dim king As JObject = DirectCast(parsed("King"), JObject)

king("Age") = 30

Dim pass As JToken

If king.TryGetValue("Pass", pass) Then
    ' has pass
End If

Dim json2 As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsed, Formatting.Indented)

' Now we remove the first and last { }
Dim ix As Integer = json2.IndexOf(ControlChars.Lf) + 1
Dim lastix As Integer = json2.LastIndexOf(ControlChars.Cr)

' The final text
Dim json3 As String = json2.Substring(ix, lastix - ix)
```